# Pascal Latest N Prime Number in Array

Tags: arrays, pascal, freepascal

I want to print array of n prime number, like if the input is 5 so it'll print [2,3,5,7,11].
This is my code

```
program prime;
type
  prime_number = array [1..10] of Integer;
var
  dataset:prime_number;
  n,i,j,count,angka:Integer;

function isPrime(a:Integer): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
    for i := 2 to round(sqrt(a)) do
    begin
       if(a mod i = 0) then isPrime:=false
       else isPrime:=true;
    end;
end;


procedure printPrime(a:Integer;var df:prime_number);
var
  number,primeCount,i: Integer;
begin
      number:=2;
      primeCount:=0;
      while (primeCount < a) do
      begin
        if(isPrime(number)) then 
        begin
          for i := 1 to a do
          begin
              df[i]:=number;
              primeCount:=primeCount+1; 
          end;    
        end;
        number:=number+1;   
      end;

end;

begin
  write('Enter n: ');read(n);
  printPrime(n,dataset);
end.
```

When I run the program it's totally fine, but it prints nothing instead of the array :( What's wrong with my code, anyone?

Answer (score 3):

I see at least a couple of issues.

First, `isPrime`: You'll want to break out of the loop as soon as you see something that divides the test value, `a`, so it should be more like

```
function isPrime(a:Integer): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
    for i := 2 to round(sqrt(a)) do
    begin
       if(a mod i = 0) then begin
         isPrime:=false;
         exit;
       end;
    end;
    isPrime:=true;
end;
```

Then, in `printPrime` you have some, frankly, odd logic.

First of all, you're not printing anything anywhere within that procedure.

Then, when you do find a prime, you initialize all values in `df` up to the size with that value, why not just set the value at `primeCount`? You know, as in

```
procedure printPrime(a:Integer;var df:prime_number);
var
  number,primeCount,i: Integer;
begin
      number:=2;
      primeCount:=0;
      while (primeCount < a) do
      begin
        if(isPrime(number)) then 
        begin
          primeCount:=primeCount+1; 
          df[primeCount]:=number;
        end;
        number:=number+1;   
      end;    
end;
```

Comment: Woow thank you about that, and yeah i forgot to make procedure to display all of the value in the array :). I'm fine now